# $f(x) =\cos(x-y) -\cos(\delta)$ plotting

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

Ok, so this is a confusing one. I'm not sure what my teacher is looking for. The problem is:

Plot any number $-\pi < y< \pi$ and pick a small number $\delta > 0$ so that the whole interval $I = (y-\delta, y+\delta) ⊆ T$ with $T=(-\pi, \pi)$.

Now define a function $f(x) =\cos(x-y)-\cos(\delta)$ and plot it on the interval $T$. Use the fact that on $T$ the cosine function takes on no value more than twice to show that:

a)$f(x)=0, x=y-\delta, y+\delta$

b)$f(x)>0$ on $ I$

c)$f(x)<0$ otherwise

I'm guessing the solution is some kind of graph, but I can't seem to find a clear graph of this function. Help! Please!

Answer (score 0):

a) Recall that $\cos x=\cos (-x)$ for all $x$

b+c) In a) you've found two points at which $f=0$, so by the hint $f\neq 0$ everywhere else.  So you just have to find out whether $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (y-\delta,y+\delta)$ or outside.

Comment: But what exactly am I putting down for my answers? Is it a graph that shows those three properties: a, b, and c? What is my delta?Do I just pick one like $\delta = 1/2$?

Comment: Your value of $\delta$ will depend on your value of $y$.  You can pick any $y$ and any $\delta$ as long as $-\pi<y-\delta<y<y+\delta<\pi$.  I think my answer essentially provides all that you need, but you can also draw a graph, I suppose.  Example values are $y=0$ and $\delta=\pi/6$.  The point is that your choices of $y,\delta$ don't matter as long as they satisfy the stated constraints.